# Why is my user being added to one table but not another

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a profile image upload system for my users. Upon signup, the php code should create a user in the table "user" and also create a user in the "profileImg" table.  I am getting no errors in my log but the user is being added to "user" but not "profileImg". Can anyone please assist. Thank you in advance.

SIGNUP.INC.PHP:

```
<?php  
session_start();
include '../dbh.php';

$respond = array(
    'status'   => true,
    'message'  => 'There was an error',
    'redirect' => '../profile.php',
    'errors',
);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorEmail = false;


if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($pwd)) {

    $respond['errors'][] = "Please fill out all fields!";
    $respond['errorEmpty'] = true;

} elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    $respond['errors'][] = "Please enter a valid email address!";
    $respond['errorEmail'] = true;

} else {

    $sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $emailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);


    if ($emailcheck > 0) {
        $respond['errors'][] = "That email address already exists!";
        $respond['errorEmail'] = true;
    } 



else {
    $encryptpwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (first, last, email, pwd)
    VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$encryptpwd')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND first='$first'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $email = $row['id'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO profileImg (email, status)
                    VALUES ('$email', 1)";

        }
    }


    }

}
}
echo json_encode($respond);
?>
```

PROFILE.PHP:

Comment: Try to replace `mysqli_num_rows` on `mysqli_affected_rows`. Docs are here - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: Why not just add a field in the users table for the profile photo? No reason to create a whole new table just for their profile photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be a violation on database level.

See this block of yours:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $email = $row['id'];
        $sqlProfile = "INSERT INTO profileImg (email, status)
                VALUES ('$email', 1)";
    }
}
```

---

I'm pretty sure that in your database the email column of profileImg table is a varchar, although you are inserting it as an int `$email = $row['id'];`

Replace that line by the this `$email = $row['email'];`

---

Code after changes:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $email = $row['email'];
        $sqlProfile = "INSERT INTO profileImg (email, status)
                VALUES ('$email', 1)";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlProfile);
    }
}
```

**Update: add `mysqli_query($conn, $sqlProfile);` to execute the query**

Comment: I had tried that previously but I just retried it and same result. adds user to "user" but not to "profileImg"

Comment: upload both tables structures and see my last update